# How to debug InfluxDB with Home Assistant suddenly hogging the CPU?

Tags: home-automation

Some weeks ago InfluxDB (running with Home Assistant) started utilizing 35-ish % of the RPi4 CPU(s) (normal usage is 2-3 %). When I restarted InfluxDB (within inside Home Assistant) it dropped to normal, but the issue reappeared after a few hours:

[image: InfluxDB are restarted at the red arrows]
(CPU usage - red arrows indicate when InfluxDB was restarted)

A few weeks later the CPU usage increased to 55-60 %, and it no longer helped to restart InfluxDB.

Yesterday, I saw it increasing to 90 %. However, after restarting InfluxDB, the usage dropped back down to about 60 %.

How do I debug this?

Thanks in advance!

- Raspberry Pi 4, 4 GB RAM
- Raspbian Bullseye
- Home Assistant 2023.2.3
- InfluxDB 4.5.0